# How can I attach a Segmented Picker in the Navigation Bar when Scrolling? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TARUn.png
In this example, the segmented picker is in the middle, and once I start scrolling, it also scrolls  but stop scrolling when reach the navigation bar, and attach it in the navigation bar as seem in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrXCl.png. How can I achieve this approach in SwiftUI?

I have tried to use the ScrollViewReader to achieve this, but I don't know if it's possible

Comment: You can use the LazyVStack’s pinned Views argument

Comment: @loremipsum it's exactly what I needed to! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`LazyVStack` comes built in with an argument for `pinnedViews`

```
LazyVStack(spacing: 1, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
    // ...
}
```

You can use it to "pin" the "header" of your `Section`

```
ScrollView {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 1, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
            ForEach(sections) { section in
                Section(header: SectionHeaderView(colorData: section)) {
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grouping-data-with-lazy-stack-views